# How to check the XHR call location in a JavaScript file using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

So like they title says, is it possible to check for the location and line of where an api is exactly being calling in the XHR Networks tab in Chrome Dev Tools? If so how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possible, by going into the ***network panel*** tab. Check the ***'Initiator'*** column.

Usually the xhr call in itself is done by a library, e.g. jquery. It might be useful to mouse over the column value to get the stack trace of the call. From there you should be able to jump to the *high-level* xhr call that interests you. See capture:

[image]